# Are there any 'home-grown' substances that can be used to clean carpet stains?

Tags: home, cleaning, carpet

I've heard of using walnuts to remove scratches on wooden furniture. Are there any plants that can be grown or foraged that have the ability to remove dirt/stains from carpets?

Comment: What type of stain(s)?

Comment: @chrisFrisina Choclate ice cream

Comment: Coffee stain removal would also be good to know! :-D

Answer (score 4):

Vinegar is known to be a cleaning agent, but I don't know what sort of stains or what sort of carpet, so it is hard to know if it would be appropriate in your circumstance.  You can make homemade vinegar a number of ways, but my method of choice is a long-standing batch of kombucha.  If I were in your shoes, I might produce a good strong kombucha vinegar, then remove it from the SCOBY, filter nicely, let a bunch of lemon rinds soak in it for several days, then TRY IT on an inconspicuous section of the carpet to see if removes stains without destroying the color/material.

Comment: When I was in middle school I did a science fair project on vinegar's effect on pigmentation in various vegetables.  I was actually interested in following up on the color changes in red cabbage, but I found something else.  Vinegar seems to reduce the color of "green" juices of veggies (I don't know whether it's chlorophyll or something else that it neutralizes).  Usually the result is more orange.